# change the limits of integration

Tags: integration

Trying to do some integrals by trigonometry substitution, If I have the following integral, I don't know how to set the new limits of integration. I have look for videos but nothing really explains it in a context I can understand.

$$\int_0^3 \frac{x}{\sqrt{36-x^2}}{\rm\, d}x$$

I get:

$x = 6\sin y$

${\rm d}x = 6\cos y {\rm\,d}y$

$\sin y=x/6$

How do I change the limits of the integral? Am I having problems seeing how this is done. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's how: when $x=0$, what is $y$? when $x=3$, what is $y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 
$$x=6\sin y$$
Replace 3 as such,

Find what y gives x=3
$$6\sin y=x$$
$$6\sin y=3$$
$$\sin y=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$y=\frac{π}{6}$$
Try it yourself for 0.  :)

> I know $y=nπ+(-1)^n\sin^{-1} x$ but for simplicity try to take angles between$[0,π]$$$$$It doesn't matter what is your $n$ as $$\int trignometric=0$$ for angles having difference of $nπ$$$$$ thus the areas between of extra $nπ$ cancel out.
>   $$$$But just be careful.